# MATLAB syntax length

Tags: matlab

I'm reading some MATLAB trying to pick it up. The line below is probably rather simple but I do not understand it.

I understand length will give me the length of a vector, in this case a vector which is part of a struct, index_struct.data_incl.

The actual value of index_stuct.data_incl at run time is simply 1. What is confusing me is what is inside the brackets i.e. (index_struct.data_incl == 1)? I can't work out what this line is trying to do as simple as it may be!

```
int_var                 = length(index_struct.data_incl(index_struct.data_incl == 1));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this (but think of `x` as your `index_struct.data_incl`:):

```
x = [1 4 5 13 1 1]
length(x(x==1))

ans =

     3
```

It's just counting the number of elements of your `x` vector that are equal to `1`

because `x==1` evaluates to `[1 0 0 0 1 1]` and then using [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) `x(x==1)` evaluates to `[1 1 1]` whose length is `3`;

It could have been written more simply as `sum(index_struct.data_incl == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

If I dont see the code I can only guess..., but I guess that `index_struc.data_incl`  should be a vector, with length `n` meaning that you have the option to read until `n` files, and all the values of the array should be `0` at the begining, and when you read a file you change the corresponding position in the vector `index_struc.data_incl` from 0 to 1. After some time you can see how many of these files you have read using

```
int_var = length(index_struct.data_incl(index_struct.data_incl == 1));
```

because it will give to you the number of `1` in the vector `index_struct.data_incl`.